# Microsoft Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that has a amount of transaction column (dollar amount) and a payment type column (cash, check, CC). Is there a way to query all amount of transactions that are paid with cash and get a total, paid with credit card and get a total, paid with a check and get a total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select payment_type, sum(transaction_amount)
from yourtable
group by payment_type
```

That'll return a row for each payment type, along with the total amount paid via that type.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what  needed. Is there a way to add a column for the quantity of each payment type?

Comment: Thanks again Marc. I have one more question...So i have a row that totals all cc's, cash, checks, etc. Is there a way to add all these payment types into one Grand Total?

Comment: You'd have to sum it in Access, or do another query that does `select sum(...)` with no grouping.

Comment: in expression builder for a report I have a text box where I want all cash payments totaled, what would the IIf statement look like?